# Zend_Layout doesn't appear to be encoding content as UTF-8

Tags: php, zend-framework, utf-8

I am using the MVC functionality in the Zend Framework 1.9, and it appears that Zend_Layout is not encoding the view content using UTF-8, despite this being set in the heading.

The layout script is shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <?php echo $this->headTitle(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->headMeta(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->headLink(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->headScript(); ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>£ $ &pound;</p>
        <?php echo $this->layout()->content;  ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

The view script can be found below.

```
<p>£ $ &pound;</p>
```

In the layout, the pound symbol outputs as you would expect, but it doesn't render inside the actual view.

If I remove the layout and just output the view, it comes out fine. Also if I put the $this->layout()->content inside utf8_encode it all works dandy.

I just want to know if there is a way to fix this issue IN the Zend Framework.

Answer (score 1):

By default, Views are encoded in ISO-8859-1, and not UTF-8 ; maybe this is the reason for your problem.

You'll find more explanations and an example in this section of Survive the Deep End : [5.4. Step 3: Implement Application Bootstrapping](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/a.not.so.simple.hello.world.tutorial#zfbook.a.not.so.simple.hello.world.tutorial.step3.implement.application.bootstrapping) -- it's a bit long, but some stuff there might help you...

Here is a quote from that page :

> At present, `Zend_View`, in stark
>   contrast to other components, uses a
>   default character set of ISO-8859-1
>   (as do View Helpers) which simply
>   won't do if you are going to output
>   multibyte characters

And also :

> To change the default, we should
>   instantiate a new instance of
>   `Zend_View`, set a more appropriate
>   default character encoding of UTF-8,
>   and implant this altered View object
>   into the ViewRenderer Action Helper.

And there is another way, using the .ini configuration file, explained in the next chapter ; especially, section [6.5. Step 4: Handling Setting Of Standard Component Defaults](http://www.survivethedeepend.com/zendframeworkbook/en/1.0/standardise.the.bootstrap.class.with.zend.application#zfbook.standardise.the.bootstrap.class.with.zend.application.handling.setting.of.standard.component.defaults).

Comment: The first thing I did was to use setEncoding on the view in order to change it to UTF-8 but this didn't seem to make any difference. Should I have done anything more than this?

Answer (score 1):

What is the file-encoding of your layout and your view file? Make sure that both of them are encoded with UTF-8. I strongly suspect that your view file (the one with `<p>£ $ &pound;</p>`) is not UTF-8-encoded.

The reason why you see the described behaviour is that the browser *guesses* the used encoding and switched to UTF-8 when using the layout and to some other encoding (most likely ISO-8859-x) when just displaying the view script.

You should provide the browser with a decent hint on which encoding is used. One option is using a `meta` `http-equiv` tag in your layout's `<head>`-section, another one is setting an HTTP-header (`Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8`) on your response object.

Comment: Thanks. Such a simple thing to overlook. I must have some ooooold PHP files that I keep cloning. Need to do some spring cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your bootstrap.

```
$view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
$view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
$view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type',  'text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

I generally use this function in my bootstrap

```
protected function _initDoctype()
{
$this->bootstrap('view');
    $view = $this->getResource('view');

    $view->addHelperPath(.....);
    $view->addHelperPath(.....);

    $view->setEncoding('UTF-8');
    $view->doctype('XHTML1_STRICT');
    $view->headMeta()->appendHttpEquiv('Content-Type',  'text/html;charset=utf-8');
```

}

Alternatively:

In your layout file

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And dont echo $this->headmeta() at all.

Comment: If you are bootstrapping view by $this->bootstrap('view')

Then in your config.ini file add this

resources.view[] =